# Delay Start to powershell script

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to add a time delay to this script to move the .pdfs.? So when multiple PDf's are dropped into the transfer folder wait 10 seconds before it transfers the file(s)

```bsh
$folder = 'C:\Transfers'  
$filter = '*.PDF'   

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType ## Heading ##$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
write-host "test"
Invoke-Item 'C:\Transfers\Movebat.bat'}
```

Comment: Maybe Wait-Event and a Timer as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-event?view=powershell-7

Comment: or add `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` before moving?

Comment: Where in the script do I add the "Start-Sleep -Seconds 10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sleep cmdlet.

For seconds:
`sleep -s 10`

For milliseconds:
`sleep -m 10000`

Comment: Where in the script do I add it?

Comment: According to this: "when multiple PDf's are dropped into the transfer folder wait 10 seconds before it transfers the file(s)" I would put it right before you call the bat file with invoke-item.

If that doesn't work you can also do a sleep in the .bat file with `timeout /t 10`